jet smart filter auto page reload not work
SmartFilters have 3 option to filtter the data
AJAX
Page reload
Mixed
I want to use page reload, but currently, when using the page reload, I have to click on the "Apply Filter" button. Then, the page reloads and shows the result. However, what I want is for the page to reload automatically when I select any filter value.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // Select your filter form or individual inputs
    var filters = document.querySelectorAll('.jet-smart-filters select, .jet-smart-filters input[type="checkbox"], .jet-smart-filters input[type="radio"]');

    // Add change event listener to each filter
    filters.forEach(function(filter) {
        filter.addEventListener('change', function() {
            // Adjusted to match the specific class of your apply button
            document.querySelector('.apply-filters__button').click();
        });
    });
});

